# How order in WHERE condition affects a query using PDO::bindParam()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, where-clause

I have the following WHERE condition

```
WHERE table.status IN ('Active') AND table.endDate < :endDate AND :user IN (table.userId, mach.techId, mach.respId) AND 1
```

I bind the parameters and it works, but if the condition is

```
WHERE :user IN (table.userId, mach.techId, mach.respId) AND table.status IN ('Active') AND table.endDate < :endDate AND 1
```

This doesn't works.

Is there any rule about ordering conditions? Also, the `endDate` condition is always ignored.

Sidenote: if you're wondering about that `AND 1` at the end, it's because I "construct" my query condition.

Comment: could you show the php sequence please?

Comment: I already figured it out, but it was important to show that I used a foreach loop to use bindParam().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem thanks to this accepted response.
[PDO - bindParam not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218797/pdo-bindparam-not-working)

I realized that I miss an important detail on my question. I used bindParam() inside a foreach loop. I just switched bindParam() to bindValue() and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any rule about ordering conditions?

For the named placeholders - no.

> This doesn't work.

Well, debug it.
Start from setting PDO in exception mode

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

and studying the error message

Comment: When I say that it doesn't works, I mean that the query is successful, but doesn't return anything, as I couldn't find any results matching those rules.