# PDO BindParam and BindValue not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindparam

I've tried looking but cannot find why my code is not working.

Here is what I cannot get to work - the query doesn't return anything, in fact the processing stops at the execute.

If I hardcode the values in the `execute` it works:

```
$CID = $_POST [ 'loginPageCID' ];
$LID = $_POST [ 'loginPageLID' ];
$PWD = $_POST [ 'loginPagePwd' ];

require_once('connectdb.php');

$sql = "

    SELECT u.*, c.cname, c.cstatus
    FROM t_users u, t_customers c
    WHERE u.cid = ?
    AND c.cid = u.cid
    AND u.login_id  = ?
    AND u.pwhash = ?

    ";

$stmt = $conn->prepare ( $sql );

$stmt->execute (array(1, 'su1', 'hello'));

$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

With the above it works, but if I try to use variables the execute seems to silently fail:

```
$CID = $_POST [ 'loginPageCID' ];
$LID = $_POST [ 'loginPageLID' ];
$PWD = $_POST [ 'loginPagePwd' ];

require_once('connectdb.php');

$sql = "

    SELECT u.*, c.cname, c.cstatus
    FROM ids_users u, ids_customers c
    WHERE u.cid = ?
    AND c.cid = u.cid
    AND u.login_id  = ?
    AND u.pwhash = ?

    ";

$stmt = $conn->prepare ( $sql );

$stmt->bindParam(1, $CID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $LID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $PWD, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute (); // fails here

$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Edit:

connectdb.php is as follows:

```
$conn;

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Have you [enabled exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)? If so, nothing should silently fail.

Comment: @tadman - have added the code for creating the connection to the question.

Comment: Have a closer look at the result objects you're getting back. Double-check your error log for any notifications.

Comment: Note: `echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();` - Make shure you don't use that code in production. The message might contain the password (though I'm not sure).

Comment: `$stmt->execute (); // fails here` - How do you know it fails there?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - I plastered the code with noddy debug "echo" statements and that leads me to believe it fails at the execute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found the solution in this post:

[PDO - bindParam not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218797/pdo-bindparam-not-working)

in the second answer, where the user suggested to avoid using the bindParam or bindValue functions as PDO has already a shorter way to dinamically assign parameters to the SQL query.